# Using overlayButtons on FusionCharts with javascript links

Tags: fusioncharts

I would like to use a javascript function link such as 'link:j-myJS-data' for drill down type charts.  I have everything working great to drill down but cannot figure out how to incorporate the overlayButton through the configureLink when drilling down.  At present, I can drill down but cannot go back.  Can anyone provide a basic example of how I may go about this?  Is it even possible?

I thought I could add my own "Back" button to hande this as one option.  I do not want to use a jsonURL as there is a lot of data and many paramertes need to be passed resutling in a long links and a lot of extra data in the JSON.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options available to create a drill-down chart with FusionCharts XT. Here is a [table](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/?DrillDown/LinkFormat.html) which explains all of them, with each one's syntax.

The method that you've used is the JavaScript function link. Using this one, you won't get an overlay button to go back to the parent chart.

The overlay button is available only when a [LinkedChart](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/?DrillDown/LinkedCharts.html) is created.

So there are 2 ways that you could go about:

1. You could change all your charts to use the LinkedCharts technique. Here is a [blog post detailing how LinkedCharts can be created using PHP + MySQL](http://blog.fusioncharts.com/2012/03/javascript-linkedcharts-in-php-and-mysql-using-fusioncharts-xt/). If you aren't using PHP, the general idea shown still applies to any server-side environment.
2. You could create a separate button sitting near the chart, and this button would re-create the parent chart for you.

Answer (score 0):

The button (which we call "overlay-button") can be made automatically visible using *LinkedCharts* alone.

However the overlay-button can be internally invoked using the charts' private API. Since these APIs are private, it may change between implementations and may not work as desired under certain circumstances. I would not recommend you to use this. If you are still interested in knowing more on this API, put in a comment and I will update this post.